# Pass multiple params with html link in struts 1.2

Tags: parameters, struts-1

this is my code:

```
<display:table name="paginatedList" sort="external" requestURI="/pathToMyAction.do" id="element">
<display:column titleKey="label.element.message">
    <c:if test="${readDetails}">
        <%
        Map paramMap = new HashMap();
        paramMap.put("param1", ${element.param1});
        paramMap.put("param2", ${element.param2});
        request.setAttribute("linkParams", paramMap);
        %>
        <html:link href="pathToDetails.do" name="linkParams" titleKey="label.element.viewInNewWindow" paramName="element" paramId="id" paramProperty="id" target="_blank">
            <html:img page="/images/edit.gif" border="0" align="center" />
        </html:link>
    </c:if>
</display:column>
```

But this doesn't work, I can't paste the error message right now, but it fails in:

```
paramMap.put("param1", ${element.param1});
```

The original was:

```
<html:link href="pathToMyAction.do" titleKey="label.element.viewInNewWindow" paramName="element" paramId="id" paramProperty="id" target="_blank">
  <html:img page="/images/edit.gif" border="0" align="center" />
</html:link>
```

With this I only get the `id`, and I'm trying to get more than 1 parameter, and I'm unable.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was missing:

```
<bean:define id="myParam1" name="element" property="param1" />
<bean:define id="myParam2" name="element" property="param2" />
```

Finally my code would be like this:

```
<display:table name="paginatedList" sort="external" requestURI="/pathToMyAction.do" id="element">
<display:column titleKey="label.element.message">
    <c:if test="${readDetails}">
        <bean:define id="myParam1" name="element" property="param1" />
        <bean:define id="myParam2" name="element" property="param2" />
        <%
        Map paramMap = new HashMap();
        paramMap.put("param1", myParam1);
        paramMap.put("param2", myParam2);
        request.setAttribute("linkParams", paramMap);
        %>
        <html:link action="pathToDetails.do" name="linkParams" titleKey="label.element.viewInNewWindow" target="_blank">
            <html:img page="/images/edit.gif" border="0" align="center" />
        </html:link>
    </c:if>
</display:column>
```

I hope this helps to others with similar problems :).